# javascript - array does not get set back to [] (blank)

Tags: javascript, arrays, parse-platform, cloud

I have this code and every time that the first for loop starts again I want it to reset the array to blank as it is using a new user, but I get an out put with all the values in one array.

```
var items = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < userArray.length; i++) {

        items.length = 0;
        for (var i2 = 0; i2 < test.length; i2++) {

            var UserFavourite = Parse.Object.extend("UserFavourite");
            var queryUserFav = new Parse.Query(UserFavourite);
            queryUserFav.equalTo('item', test[i2].get('item'));
            queryUserFav.equalTo('school', test[i2].get('school'));
            queryUserFav.equalTo('user1', userArray[i])
            queryUserFav.find().then(function(res) {

                    for (var i3 = 0; i3 < res.length; i3++){
                        var item = res[i3];
                        var itemName = item.get('item');
                        items.push(itemName);
                        if (items !== []) {
                            console.log(items.toString()+" + ")
                        }
                    }

            });

        }
    }
```

userArray.length is equal to 2 and test.length is equal to 20. If you were wondering. And when it get to the first for loop I want the array to be set back to blank but it isn't?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Given that *items* is an array, the expression `items !== []` will always return true since you are comparing different objects. Perhaps you meant `items.length != 0` or more simply `if (items.length)`.

Comment: @RobG okay but that doesn't affect why the array doesn't get reset to blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thnk you should use set this:

```
items.length = 0
```

because items = []

creates a new array which is not the same.

Also add some promises to make the async requests wait

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
items.length = 0;
```

instead of:

```
items = [];
```

Comment: Your answer should be `items.length == 0` instead of a single `=`

Comment: @jasonscript I was referring to line 2 - i.e. clearing the array.

Comment: @jasonscript items.length == 0, doesn't work either. To array is still full

Comment: @jasonscript: `items.length == 0` does nothing by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please concatenate a "+" to the items variable in console log, like so:

```
  console.log(items.toString()+" + ");
```

Just for debugging purposes to see if the array is actually being cleared or not. I believe it already might be cleared.

Comment: okay i did that and ran it how do i know if it was being cleared. output was `I2014-09-02T03:39:55.597Z] Spicy Italian Sub + 
I2014-09-02T03:39:55.641Z] Spicy Italian Sub,Caribbean Chicken Lettuce Wraps + 
I2014-09-02T03:39:57.960Z] Spicy Italian Sub,Caribbean Chicken Lettuce Wraps,Buffalo Waffle Fries + `

Comment: Opss.. you have to clear the items in the array inside the success call back function.. please put in a check inside the success call back to see when you should clear the array and then clear it.. don't manually try to clear it from outside the success call back.. that should make it work

Comment: that put all three items that are returned in its own array

Comment: could you share where you placed the check? how you went about it?

Comment: @iqueqiorio the problem is your second for loop is executing before any of the success call back functions execute in the first run of the first loop, hence all the values are accumulating in a single array which would be in the second run of the first loop..  to solve this problem you have to handle any updates to the global items variable inside the success of fail call backs.. since i don't know exactly the scope of what you want to do here.. i can't recommend any other way of doing it.. but the current way will definitely not work..

Comment: my goal is to reset the length of the array to 0 every time the first loop is called, any thoughts on how to get around this? I update the example with something i tried but didn't work

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle link, one that console logs something, please exclude anything that is unnecessary, then i can debug it at my end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60467/discussion-between-iqueqiorio-and-lakmal-caldera).

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're executing a loop and triggering async code.

Your loop will completely finish before the first bit of async code is executed:

- i == 0
- reset `items`
- loop over `test` (20 items)

  - queue up a `find()` with async success handler
- i == 1
- reset `items`
- loop over `test` (20 items)

  - queue up a `find()` with async success handler
- ... some time later when `find()` calls finish ...
- call each async block using the `items` array

Unless there's some other code you're not showing that needs to access the `items` array, just create it inside your success handler instead:

```
queryUserFav.find().then(function(res) {
  // create array here:
  var items = [];

  for (var i3 = 0; i3 < res.length; i3++){
    var item = res[i3];
    var itemName = item.get('item');
    items.push(itemName);
    if (items !== []) {
      console.log(items.toString()+" + ")
    }
  }
});
```